# sharekit - posting link ot the wall

Tags: iphone, facebook, sharekit

I'm trying to post a link on the facebook wall. I mean I can post a link like: http://domain.com, but what I want to do is to get TEXT that is link to domain.com. 
Facebook, of course, doesn't allow this so the published result won't be LINK but LINK.

I saw this behaviour in Mashable iphone RSS reader. Result is linked title title on FB wall.

Also, in this application user is presented with empty text field and under it there is the title that will be published as a link on FB wall. Under it there is standard message:sent over xxx iphone App.

So my questions are:
1. how to publish link on FB (what do I have to change in FB API found in ShareKit)
2. how to grab title of what's being published and put it under text field in the facebook dialog view.

SHKFacebook.m

```
if (item.shareType == SHKShareTypeURL)
{
    self.pendingFacebookAction = SHKFacebookPendingStatus;

    SHKFBStreamDialog* dialog = [[[SHKFBStreamDialog alloc] init] autorelease];
    dialog.delegate = self;
    dialog.userMessagePrompt = SHKLocalizedString(@"Enter your message:");
    dialog.attachment = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"{\
                         \"name\":\"%@\",\
                         \"href\":\"%@\"\
                         }",


                         item.title == nil ? SHKEncodeURL(item.URL) : SHKEncode(item.title),
                         SHKEncodeURL(item.URL)
                         ];
    dialog.defaultStatus = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ @ %@",item.title,[item.URL absoluteString]];

    dialog.actionLinks = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[{\"text\":\"Get %@\",\"href\":\"%@\"}]",
                          SHKEncode(SHKMyAppName),
                          SHKEncode(SHKMyAppURL)];



    [dialog show];

}
```

Thank you for taking look at this,
L

Answer (score 0):

I am not that familiar with ShareKit as I felt it was too complex for a simple task like posting to Facebook, Twitter or Email. Therefore I came up with my own lib [BMSocialShare](http://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare). Maybe taking a look at my source can give you a hint on doing what you are trying to achieve with ShareKit: https://github.com/blockhaus/BMSocialShare/blob/dev/iOS/BMSocialShare/BMSocialShare/BMSocialShare.m